# Sort an Array after size but with multible identical values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this Javascript array which is generated by user inputs in a form (a score calculator of sorts). Here's an example:

```
var finalCount = [2600,200,36,36,400,2,0,0];
```

Each value represents a players total score. I then need to sort the array, so that I get I get a second array with the total overall position, and keeping the player order fixed! The desired array would (in this example) look like this:

```
var positionResult = [1,3,4,4,2,5,6,6];
```

As you can see the score can be the same between some players, and if they are, they share that position in the overal result... So, how do I generate positionResult from finalCount ??

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the code you got so far :)

Comment: Have tried tons of various things, but had to delete again, so I am clueless. Sorry

Comment: the dupe I posted gives `1,
  3,
  4,
  4,
  2,
  6,
  7,
  7` is that not correct for 7 plays?

Comment: While there's bound to exist a more optimized and thought out solution, you could solve it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/olian04/6neadbgk/

Comment: @mplungjan, if the duplicate does not give the wanted result, you could reopen the question.